# Apex case sharing for customer community users

Tags: apex, community, apex-managed-sharing

I'm hoping someone can help me understand the best way to approach the following requirement?

**Requirement:** allow community users on different accounts to share cases with one another.

**Current Setup:**

Our organization wide default for cases is set to private

We’re using customer community and company community licenses

We have a community sharing setting for cases where access is determined by User:Account = Case:Contact.Account

**Use Case:** a case is created by a company communities user (Account A) and they want to share it with an customer community user (Account B)
We don’t want customer community users to see cases created by company users unless given permission for that specific record.

**Business context:** we have internal employees that share cases with contractors and vice versa.

I've read about apex sharing but I'm seeing conflicting documentation so I'm wondering if someone has achieved this before.

Best,

Kevin

Comment: Apex managed sharing is not available for Customer Community license. You need to use Customer Community Plus license for that

Comment: Thanks, @SantanuBoral! If we had the Customer Community plus license do you have a recommendation on how to best approach this requirement?

Our Ideal state would be that when someone is @mentioned on a case the apex managed sharing gives them access to the ticket. Do you know if this is possible?